# Swift Tabbed Bar 2 URLs

Tags: swift

I'm writing a simple swift app - I have two tabs at the bottom calling different URLs. I can't differentiate between them so both tabs load the first URL.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

// Add WKWebView programmatically


class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    var webView : WKWebView
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 414, height: 736))
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(webView)
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let views = ["webView" : webView]
        let h = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[webView]|", options: [], metrics: nil , views: views)
        let w = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[webView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
        view.addConstraints(h)
        view.addConstraints(w)
        let url = NSURL(string: "https://bing.com")
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)
        webView.load(urlRequest)
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}

class ViewController3: UIViewController {
    var webView1 : WKWebView
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.webView1 = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 414, height: 736))
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(webView1)
        webView1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let views1 = ["webView1" : webView1]
        let h = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[webView1]|", options: [], metrics: nil , views: views1)
        let w = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[webView1]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views1)
        view.addConstraints(h)
        view.addConstraints(w)
        let url1 = NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com")
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url1! as URL)
        webView1.load(urlRequest)
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

I have tried to separate the url requests and I'm sure its a simple error on my part as I'm very new to swift and Xcode!

Comment: where have you created the tabs? in storyboard, then confirm that you assigning the different viewControllers on both tabs.

Comment: Thanks Bhavin... year tabs were created in storyboard - when I checked the viewControllers they were both the same - amended and working great!

Comment: your most welcome